# My job scrapes only the last page instead of all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scraping job only seems to write to CSV the last page of the website.  I assume this is because it is looping through all pages and then writes to the csv.  It does scrape the elements and prints them in the console.  Do you have to loop through and write to csv for each page straight away as it cannot store the data?   I have tried adjusting my code to accommodate this but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

I have also tried a different menthod but the same thing appears to be happening in https://www.pastebin.ca/3863340

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import csv
    import requests
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from random import shuffle
    import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.bookmaker.com.au/sports/soccer/')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

time.sleep(1)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".market-match:nth-child(2) .market-group a , .market-match:nth-child(1) .market-group a")
elem_href1 = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
print(elem_href1)
print (len(elem_href1))
shuffle(elem_href1)
for link in elem_href1:
    driver.get(link)
    ...
    time.sleep(2)

    # link
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3 a[Href*='/sports/soccer']")
    elem_href = []
    for elem in elems:
     print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
     elem_href.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

    # TEAM
    langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".row:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)")
    langs_text = []

    for lang in langs:
        print(lang.text)
        langs_text.append(lang.text)

    time.sleep(0)

    # odds
    langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.odds.quickbet")
    langs1_text = []

    for lang in langs1:
        print(lang.text)
        langs1_text.append(lang.text)

    time.sleep(0)

    with open('vtg12.csv', 'a', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs1_text, langs_text, elem_href):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what would you expect it to be?

Comment: I'm wanting to scrape all the data into one csv file and it's not doing that.

Comment: I mean, show an hand-made example of how the csv file would look like

Comment: @HaydenDarcy what output do you get when you print(row) just above writer.write(row)?

Comment: @chasmani Here's what I see in console: http://textuploader.com/d4ikb  and my code is here: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1508850557648.txt . Kind of weird how google inspect and python console pick up different elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the CSV every single iteration and hence only last record remains when the script ends.

Change

```
with open('vtg12.csv', 'a', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs1_text, langs_text, elem_href):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

to

```
with open('vtg12.csv', 'a+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs1_text, langs_text, elem_href):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

`a+` will open the file in append mode

Comment: Legend.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: I don't get this. What is the different between `a` (write at the end) and `a+` (read and write at the end) in a write only enviroment like this? I got the same result execution both codes.

Comment: @VMRuiz, i believe you are right. Hayden, did you test if the issue was fixed? Also which version of python you are using

Comment: @VMRuiz Indeed, it appears its back. Strange how some jobs this does not happen.  I wonder what causes it.

Comment: Are you running multiple instances in parallel?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, I am unsure why it is doing this.  The job works reliably otherwise

Comment: I can't think of any other reason, other than something outside blanking your file

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've tested this job on another website.  It worked but after about 10 tests I started getting:  NameError: name 'lang1_text' is not defined.   https://ibb.co/eNAjT6 and https://pastebin.com/n503D17S and error code: https://ibb.co/bwc9vm

Answer (score 2):

At the very top:

```
def append_to_csv(csv_list, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'a', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        data = [csv_list]
        a.writerows(data)
```

Then replace

```
with open('vtg12.csv', 'a', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs1_text, langs_text, elem_href):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

with:

```
for row in zip(langs_text, langs2_text, langs_text, elem_href):

    append_to_csv(row, 'vtg12.csv')
```

Comment: Hmmm for me it displays a blank csv