# Unable to find xpath list trying to use wild card contains text or style

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to find an XPATH for this site the XPath under “Main Lists”.  I have so far:

```
//div[starts-with(@class, ('sm-CouponLink_Label'))]
```

However this finds 32 matches…

```
`//div[starts-with(@class, ('sm-CouponLink_Label'))]`[contains(text(),'*')or[contains(Style(),'*')]
```

Unfortunately in this case I am wanting to use XPaths and not CSS.

It is for this [site](https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/), my [code](http://textuploader.com/d4efx) is here and here's an [image](https://ibb.co/mcwUT6) of XPATH I am after.

I have also tried:

CSS: `div:nth-child(1) > .sm-MarketContainer_NumColumns3 > div > div`

Xpath equiv...: `//div[1]//div[starts-with(@class, ('sm-MarketContainer_NumColumns3'))]//div//div`
Though it does not appear to work.

*UPDATED*
WORKING CSS: `div.sm-Market:has(div >div:contains('Main Lists'))   * > .sm-CouponLink_Label`

Xpath: `//div[Contains(@class, ('sm-Market'))]//preceding::('Main Lists')//div[Contains(@class, ('sm-CouponLink_Label'))]`

Not working as of yet..

Though I am unsure Selenium have equivalent for :has

Alternatively...

Something like:

```
//div[contains(text(),"Main Lists")]//following::div[contains(@class,"sm-Market")]//div[contains(@class,"sm-CouponLink_Label")]//preceding::div[contains(@class,"sm-Market_HeaderOpen ")]
```

(wrong area)

Comment: You can’t use wildcards in Selenium.  To get around this go:
//div[@class='sm-CouponLink ']//div[starts-with(@class, ('sm-CouponLink_Label'))]  and loop through 30+ elements until you get your match.  
Hope that helps.

Comment: what did you try to do with the additional predicate `[contains(text(),'*')or[contains(Style(),'*')]`? I guess you want to filter further to take only `div` that has inner text or has attribute `style`, is this correct?

Comment: @har07 Correct.  The page contains text and also style which is basically text but called style.  So if you did wildcard text it would not get 6 tabs but text or style should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all required elements with below piece of code:

```
league_names = [league for league in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-Market" and .//div="Main Lists"]//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-CouponLink_Label"]') if league.text]
```

This should return you list of only non-empty nodes

Comment: If you want just 5 non-empty elements from main list, check updated

Comment: This returns 6 for me still

Comment: Did you try this one `league_names = [league for league in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-Market" and .//div="Main Lists"]//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-CouponLink_Label"]') if league.text]`?

Comment: I'm testing it in Chrome inspect at the moment.  That gave me zero matches

Comment: There seem to be be hidden characters. Try this one `//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-Market" and .//div="Main Lists"]//div[normalize-space(@class)="sm-CouponLink_Label"]`

Comment: I tried in Firefox and Chrome this solution and it works.

Comment: @Andersson Oh right, sorry.  It gives me 6 matches (need 5)

Comment: The XPath itself returns you *all* nodes while using provided python line will return you *only non-empty nodes*

Comment: @Andersson I didn't know about the "normalize-space". Thank you.

Comment: @Andersson Any idea why this job does not write to csv correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032886/my-job-scrapes-only-the-last-page-instead-of-all-of-them .

Comment: @HaydenDarcy, I haven't much experience with `csv` library, so it need some time to investigate the issue... I'm currently working, so will take a look at it later

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want to narrow down further the result of your first XPath to return only `div` that has inner text or has attribute `style`. In this case you can use the following XPath :

```
//div[starts-with(@class, ('sm-CouponLink_Label'))][@style or text()]
```

---

**UPDATE**

As you clarified further, you want to get `div` with class 'sm-CouponLink_Label' that resides in the 'Main Lists' section. For this purpose, you should try to incorporate the 'Main Lists' in the XPath somehow. This is one possible way (formatted for readability) :

```
//div[
    div/div/text()='Main Lists'
]//div[
    starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')
        and
    normalize-space()
]
```

Notice how `normalize-space()` is used to filter out empty `div` from the result. This should return 5 elements as expected, here is the result when I tested in Chrome :

[image]

Comment: https://ibb.co/mcwUT6 . I've circled in yellow the values I want which are under the Main List.  This gets too many values unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, only the data under main section.  I've marked with an x that I don't want a tab with no writing on it though as job won't be able to click an element that does not navigate anywhere

Comment: //div[div/div/text()='Main Lists']//div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')] gives me 6 (need 5).   While //div[div/div/text()='Main Lists']//div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')andnormalize-space()] is not showing me anything